# Can't get rewrite rules working

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, wp-redirect

Basically I want to rewrite:
/edit/test-post
to an existing page with a parameter:
/edit?e=test-post

From the [examples in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Rewrite#Examples) I created:

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array','my_insert_rewrite_rules' );
add_filter( 'query_vars','my_insert_query_vars' );
add_action( 'wp_loaded','my_flush_rules' );

// flush_rules() if our rules are not yet included
function my_flush_rules(){
    $rules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );

    if ( ! isset( $rules['(edit)/(\d*)$'] ) ) {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }
}

// Adding a new rule
function my_insert_rewrite_rules( $rules )
{
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['(edit)/(\d*)$'] = 'edit?&e=$matches[2]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}

// Adding the id var so that WP recognizes it
function my_insert_query_vars( $vars )
{
    array_push($vars, 'e');
    return $vars;
}
```

However, I simply cannot get it working, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the `e=` parameter value to be a string or digits? In your question intro it's a string/slug, but in the code your pattern `(edit)/(\d*)$` would match 'edit' and then digits.

Comment: It's a slug actually. However, that didn't fix it. :(

Comment: I've had problems with rewrite_rules myself. In my case I didn't even mess with the rules -- I just defined a custom post type with a slug that was different from the post type name. The new slug didn't work until I deleted the rewrite_rules option in the database manually (note -- not on a production site.)  This leads me to believe that the WP code is buggy.  Let me know if you figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By 'existing page' do you mean a WordPress page? My experience with rewrites is routing everything to index.php with whatever extra query vars you need, I think attempting to route it to `edit` is one of your issues, not entirely clear on your intent there.

Go download [Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) if you don't already have it, it's a great tool for testing these things out.

I tested out the following rule to verify it works. All requests to `/edit/*` load a page named 'edit', `get_query_var('e')` returns the correct value for `e` in my template.

Note I didn't flush the rules here, I usually just visit the `Settings > Permalinks` page and click save to flush whenever I change them.

```
<?php

add_action( 'init', 'my_rewrites_init' );
function my_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'edit/([^/]+)/?',
        'index.php?pagename=edit&e=$matches[1]',
        'top' );
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_query_vars' );
function my_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'e';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked! Thanks for the solution and Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer, I'll be playing with it :)